# Make a T-SQL function case sensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-sensitive, collate

I have the following T-SQL function

```
FUNCTION dbo.UrlEncode(@url NVARCHAR(1024))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(3072)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE  @urlReturn NVARCHAR(3072)

   SET @urlReturn = REPLACE(@url,'Á','%c3%81') COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS  

   SET @urlReturn = REPLACE(@url,,'á','%c3%a1')   

    RETURN @urlReturn
END
```

But if I run:

```
SELECT dbo.UrlEncode('Áreá')
```

it returns

```
%c3%a1re%c3%a1
```

I need it to return

```
%c3%81re%c3%a1
```

Is there a way a can make the function case sensitive, I have tried `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` but without success

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the case sensitive collation next to the part to be replaced. 
Second `REPLACE` should then be applied on the result of the previous `REPLACE`:

```
DECLARE @urlReturn NVARCHAR(3072)
SET @urlReturn = REPLACE(@url ,'Á' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ,'%c3%81' )  

SET @urlReturn = REPLACE( @urlReturn ,'á','%c3%a1') 
SELECT @urlReturn
```